# Generate PDF from Gridview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, pdf, gridview

I am using 4 gridviews on my page. I need to generate a pdf file which should be accessible on a button click and should contain these 4 grids. 
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

We have used [WKHTMLTOPDF](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) for our PDF's and it has worked very well. You can use it with a URL which it will then convert to a pdf which can then be sent to the users browser. So you could give it the url of your page with the gridview and then it would return a pdf. There are third party providers that can do the conversion for you, such as [PDFCrowd](http://pdfcrowd.com/), however this comes at a cost. If I recall correctly they provide a C# wrapper for you to use so it is pretty simple. There is also [iText PDF](http://itextpdf.com/), I have never used it though so cannot comment on it.

Hope this gives you a  good start.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with [Amyuni WebkitPDF](http://www.amyuni.com/en/webkitpdf/). It is a free tool for HTML to PDF or XAML/XPS convertion. You can pass the URL of the page to the library and obtain a PDF file as result that you can send to the browser.

*Usual disclaimer applies.*